# Should deep links on comercial sites be flagged as spam if there is no added value

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

I stumbled over the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17248552/1699210), which I would suspect being an attempt just to to place a link, since there is no answer or blog at all.
I am just not sure if this is just paranoia.

The question, is should suspected spam be flagged rather too often than too rarely.

Comment: This seems like a _thank you_ answer, since they are stating they implemented the code, I would flag for mod as not an answer.

Comment: That's just a non answer rant/noise but not spam. Flagged. Take a glance in the user profile on such cases, if you see more answers like that all with links then you should suspect, flag as "other" and alert the moderators for possible spammer.

Comment: `deleted by Bill the Lizard♦ 23 mins ago`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disregarding the fact that the example you linked wasn't actually an answer... Yes, links that do not add value or context to an answer need to be removed or flagged as spam (preferably just edit (or suggest an edit) before flagging).

Commonly new users think they can get some free Google juice by dropping a link to one of their sites into a StackOverflow question or answer, what they don't realise is that the system automatically inserts a `rel="nofollow"` into the anchor for all authors until they pass a certain rep level (5K IIRC).

Comment: The soecond part is the one I was focused on and I did not know that there already exists a clever solution.